# AHK and US-INT keyboard: Why are "dead" keys no longer swallowed?

Tags: autohotkey

I normally use the United States-International keyboard layout. This layout has several keys set as "dead" keys for diacritic marks - for example, pressing <kbd>^</kbd> is a dead key; it appears to do nothing until the next key is hit; if that key is one that the circumflex is an allowable diacritic, it replaces it with the marked key - that is, if I press <kbd>^</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd>, I will get **â** - but if I press a key that it's not an allowed diacritic for, I will get the circumflex followed by the letter, e.g., <kbd>^</kbd> follows by <kbd>h</kbd> gives me **^h**.

I wrote a AHK script that adds the diacriticalized characters for Esperanto (see below). It used to work "transparently" and matched the behavior described above. However, recently, the behavior seems to have changed: it no longer "swallows" the diacritic, and inserts a backspace before inserting the character desired.

In other words, if I type "The Esperanto character that sounds like English 'ch' is " and then type <kbd>^</kbd> then <kbd>c</kbd>, it *replaces* the space following "is" with the **ĉ**, and on the next keystroke, whatever it is, acts like I had hit <kbd>^</kbd> then that key.

Why? and How do I fix this?

```
#Hotstring ? C * 

; Esperanto diacriticalized characters

::^c::ĉ
::^C::Ĉ
::^g::ĝ
::^G::Ĝ
::^h::ĥ
::^H::Ĥ
::^j::ĵ
::^J::Ĵ
::^s::ŝ
::^S::Ŝ
::~u::ŭ
::~U::Ŭ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I’m not sure *why* it works this way, but I was able to get it working by turning off the automatic backspacing and manually adding my own. The revised AHK script is as follows:

```
#Hotstring ? C * B0
; Acts only as a supplement to a keyboard that (a) does not
; have these characters defined _and_ uses ^ and ~ as "dead"
; keys to apply accents.

::^c::{bs 2}ĉ
::^C::{bs 2}Ĉ
::^g::{bs 2}ĝ
::^G::{bs 2}Ĝ
::^h::{bs 2}ĥ
::^H::{bs 2}Ĥ
::^j::{bs 2}ĵ
::^J::{bs 2}Ĵ
::^s::{bs 2}ŝ
::^S::{bs 2}Ŝ
::~u::{bs 2}ŭ
::~U::{bs 2}Ŭ
::^::^
::~::~
```

The `B0` in the `#Hotstring` directive turns off the automatic backspacing. With that option in effect in the original script, typing <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> would result in `^cĉ`, so by inserting two backspaces before it (`{bs 2}`), I get rid of the extraneous `^c` before inserting the `ĉ`.

The last two lines, replacing the caret and tilde with themselves, don’t have an obvious explanation for the reason that they're needed, but they ensure that the behavior is consistent with the standard deadkey usage, so that if I type <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> I get the expected `^c` instead of an unexpected `ĉ`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I maybe missed something simple with hotstrings, but I couldn't really make it work without trying to do some even further trickery.

I figured an `InputHook`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputHook.htm)</sup> implementation could work pretty well.
It might be overkill/stupid though, since it basically just creates a custom implementation for a hotstring. But well, at least it works.

```
key_map := { "c": "ĉ"
           , "g": "ĝ"
           , "h": "ĥ"
           , "j": "ĵ"
           , "s": "ŝ"
           , "u": "ŭ" }

ih := InputHook("V")
ih.OnChar := Func("OnChar")
ih.Start()

OnChar(_, char)
{
    if (StrLen(char) != 2 || SubStr(char, 1, 1) != "^" || !(key := diacriticalize(SubStr(char, 2))))
        return
    fObj := Func("SendReplacement").Bind(key)
    SetTimer, % fObj, -0
}

diacriticalize(key)
{
    global key_map
    if key is upper
        return Format("{:U}", key_map[key])
    else
        return key_map[key]
}

SendReplacement(key)
{
    SendInput, % "{BS 2}" key
}
```

So what's happening?

First a map for the key replacements is defined.
Adding any extra dead key combinations for `^` will work just fine.

The input hook is created with only the `V`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputHook.htm#vis)</sup> option.
This makes it so that it doesn't consume input while processing it.

Then, with `.OnChar`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputHook.htm#OnChar)</sup> we define a function that runs every time the input receives a new character.
The functions always receives just one character, except when a dead key is used it'll receive e.g `^c`.
This is why we check if the input length is two and why we use `SubStr()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SubStr.htm)</sup> to transform `^c` to just `c`.
`SubStr(char, 1, 1) != "^"` also ensures that the pressed deadkey was `^`, and not e.g `¨`. Otherwise `¨c` would produce `ĉ`.

Then in the user defined function `diacriticalize()` we return the corresponding diacriticalized key from the `key_map` (if possible). If the input key was in uppercase, return the diacriticalized key in uppercase as well.
If there is no matching key in the `key_map`, nothing is returned. Which makes the `|| !(key := ...)` part do its trick to also return if the input key wasn't valid.

Then the timer<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm)</sup> trickery is done just to execute the replacement outside of the `OnChar()` function in another thread to avoid problems with send command running too early.
Basically the period `-0` just means to run once immediately.
The function which the timer will is defined as a function object that has a parameter (the key) bound to it with `.Bind()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Func.htm#Bind)</sup>.

Comment: If I have to resort to this, I will, but I'd prefer not to - and I can't use ^u for ŭ because my mixed-language text processing often includes text that includes û alongside text that includes ŭ, so I'd have to add a second test for using ~ as the deadkey.

Comment: Thank you for your effort; I did find something that works, though I have my doubts about it working with a no-dead-key keyboard (hence the comments in the revised script). See my self-answer.

Comment: Hmm yes, it would not work on a non dead key keyboard layout. Also, your answer was the first thing I tried and it doesn't work at all for me. But good that you got it working. That one is definitely better.